# Probability of intersection is positive given $\sum_{k=1}^nP(B_k) > n-1$

Tags: probability-theory

If $\{B_k\}$ are events such that $\sum_{k=1}^nP(B_k) > n-1$, then $P(\cap_{k=1}^nB_k) > 0$.

My attempt:

$$\begin{aligned}P(\cap_{k=1}^nB_k)& = 1-P(\cup_{k=1}^nB_k^c) \\&\ge 1 - \sum_{k=1}^nP(B_k^c)\\&= 1- \sum_{k=1}^n(1-P(B_k)) \\&= 1-[n - \sum_{k=1}^nP(B_k)]\end{aligned}$$

However, we are given $\sum_{k=1}^nP(B_k) > n-1$ and I'm not quite sure how to simplify $[n - \sum_{k=1}^nP(B_k)]$. If it's equal to $n$ then we get zero; however, if it's greater than $n$ we have a negative number and our probability would be greater than one - which is impossible..

Comment: Looks like you have it! Notice that $\sum_{k=1}^n P(B_k) > n-1$ implies that $\sum_{k=1}^n P(B_k)-n+1 > 0$, and that is exactly what you end up with on the right hand side.

Comment: Oh wow - that is very simple.. Thanks for pointing it out!